# How to change the default value of stage field

Tags: salesforce

i am trying to change the default value of the Stage Standard Object at Opportunity

The steps i took :

Create a workflow rule with Rule Criteria
Opportunity: Created Date Not EQUAL To null

Evaluation Criteria Evaluate the rule when a record is created.

Add the action as a field update and select the value for the pick list

Activate the rule

but there is nothing happened as the default value remains -NONE-

What am i missing? As am new at salesforce also i don't wanna use trigger or buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no option to make the stage field has a default value at the beginning unless you click on Save only in this case the value will be changed 
and the steps will work correctly once you click on save button

Answer (score 0):

The selected answer is correct, I've added a few links for anyone else looking for a solution to this issue. Hard to believe this is not standard functionality. Also don't hold your breathe, from the link at the bottom where the idea has been submitted it has been over 9 years and is still on the "PRODUCT TEAM REVIEW".  Crazy.

Workarounds:

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000003628&language=en_US
https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000i4HIAAY

Salesforce idea:

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrKdAAK